# NavigationView widget, complete animation before changes between Activities

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using NavigationView widget to create a side menu to use with my app. I've decided to use separate activities for each item in NavigationView menu. So, if I open, for example, "Settings" voice will be loaded Settings Activity. It's working like expected but the problem is that NavigationView don't have time to complete close animation `mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();` that new activity is started. How I can add somekind of delay to allow to complete `mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();` before start new activity?

p.s. Moving `mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();` before startActivity doesn't help.

Here's my code:

```
private void addDrawerItems() {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menu_main:
                        //Do something
                        break;
                    case R.id.menu_monitor:
                        Intent i = new Intent(Main_activity.this, Monitor_Activity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case R.id.menu_settings:
                        //Do something
                        break;
                }
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: well first of all its a bad habit to call new activities with navigation view..batter to use fragments...you can make delay by using handler's postdelay method

Comment: My activity is a bit complex and I've inside some activities already a fragment selector. I've read that fragments inside fragments can create problems so I've divided into activities to avoid to waste time.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution in a forum that add a DrawerListener and start the new Activity after NavigationDrawer has finished closing animation:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        Intent i = new Intent(Main_activity.this, Monitor_Activity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```